# AWS Endpoint Service(PrivateLink) to many internal services

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-endpoint, aws-private-link

I have some APIs that is in diferent regions and some in another AWS account .All APIs is each exposed with an individual ALB. How is the best way to my customer consumer this services privately usind endpoint service from your AWS account. Would I create an NLB to each ALB e criate a Endpoint Service to each NLB?

I know how to create de Endpoint service, my doubt is if create an NBL to each ALB is the best way.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Create NLBs for each ALB in your AWS account, setting up appropriate listeners, target groups, and routing rules to forward traffic to the respective ALBs in different regions/accounts.

Step 2: Create Endpoint Services for each NLB by configuring PrivateLink. This involves defining the service name, specifying the NLB as the endpoint, setting permissions, and enabling the endpoint for the desired VPCs.

Step 3: Share the Endpoint Service with customer accounts if needed. This involves setting up resource policies to allow specific AWS accounts or VPCs to access the Endpoint Service.

Step 4: Customers can then create interface VPC endpoints in their VPCs that point to the Endpoint Service you've provided. This allows them to privately access your APIs through the private connectivity established via AWS PrivateLink.